# Formatting and Calculating dates with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, calculator

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to generate a date that is:

A.) Formatted (mm/dd/yyyy)

B.) Displayed as three months later than the actual date.

I've spliced together a few things I could find and is seems to work to return the correct date, but I'm concerned it will break later in the year. Is there a  better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? The script is below, thanks in advance for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var dt = new Date();
  var month = dt.getMonth();
  var day = dt.getDate();
  var year = dt.getFullYear();

   if (month == 9) { var dt = new Date();
      var month = dt.getMonth()-8;
      var day = dt.getDate();
      var year = dt.getFullYear();
      var next_year = dt.getFullYear()+1;
      document.write(month + '-' + day + '-' + next_year)}

   else if (month == 10) { var dt = new Date();
      var month = dt.getMonth()-8;
      var day = dt.getDate();
      var year = dt.getFullYear();
      var next_year = dt.getFullYear()+1;
      document.write(month + '-' + day + '-' + next_year)}

   else if (month == 11) { var dt = new Date();
      var month = dt.getMonth()-8;
      var day = dt.getDate();
      var year = dt.getFullYear();
      var next_year = dt.getFullYear()+1;
      document.write(month + '-' + day + '-' + next_year)}

   else { var dt = new Date();
      var month = dt.getMonth()+4;
      var day = dt.getDate();
      var year = dt.getFullYear();
      document.write(month + '-' + day + '-' + year);}
  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried mocking the date? For example, setting a variable to a date next year, and plugging it into your program? What do you mean a "better" way? Also, for syntax highlighting, please add tag `javascript`. I do not think you need the HTML style tags that you included, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The built in JavaScript date library is a little obtuse, something like Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) will have a lot of built in Date math and formatting functions that would probably address what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date object has methods that allows not only to set month, date and year, but get too.

```
function getMyDate() {
  var date = new Date();

  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);

  return (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
}
document.write(getMyDate());
```

P.S. The scope of `var` is the function, not block `{}`. So, if you declared `var dt` at the top of your scope, you mustn’t use `var dt` in `if` statement. It’s a mistake.

Comment: `date.getDay()` will return the day of the week, not the date of the month

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about dealing with the last three months of the year.  Adding three months to a a date that causes it to 'overflow' will correctly set it to next year (eg adding three months to November 2015 will produce a date in February 2016).

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + 3);
document.write((dt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dt.getDate() + "-" + dt.getFullYear();
```

For what it's worth, your code looks correct.  Just unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

To print todays date you should concat the date values:

```
var d = new Date();
var str = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

if you want to add months to your date:

```
var d = new Date();
var threeMonthsFromToday = new Date(new Date(d).setMonth(d.getMonth()+3));
var str = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```